# Empty results while trying to get data from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using Node JS and MongoDb, I am trying to get data from MongoDb, but all i get is empty response even though I guess it connects to database and can access the collections.

This is my Server.js

```
// set up ======================================================================
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                 // mongoose for mongodb
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;                // set the port
var database = require('./config/database');            // load the database config
var morgan = require('morgan');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var cors = require('cors');
var messageId = {};

// configuration ===============================================================
// Connect to DB
mongoose.connect(database.remoteUrl)
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('Can not connect Error:>>',e);
    process.exit();
});
mongoose.connection.once('open', function(d) { 
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");
})
//app.use(express.static('./public'));      // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended': 'true'})); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/vnd.api+json'})); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
 });

io.set('origins', '*:*');
http = require('http'),
server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    //res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/plain'});
    //  res.write("Sever On");
    // res.end();
}),
io = io.listen(server);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('User Connected -- Server Online');   
    socket.on('message', function (msg,msgId) {
        io.emit('message', "Hello");
        console.log("message from client:", msg);
         setInterval(function(){
          io.emit("messageStatus",msgId);
      },500)
   });
});

app.use(require('./app/routes.js'));
app.listen(port);
//server.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

After I start my server, I always get connection successfully. I am currently running the server on localhost:8000

This is my config/database.js, I am using AWS to host my MongoDB

```
module.exports = {
    remoteUrl : 'mongodb://username:password@ec2-22-127-21-183.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017/testdb'

};
```

I have created a Schema based on my MongoDB, named it as userprofile.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ProfileSchema = new Schema({
    id:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    FirstName:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    LastName:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    EmailID:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    Phone:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    Address1:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    Address2:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    PinCode:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    Gender:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    ProfilePic:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    IDproof:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    UserName:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    Password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    Dob:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    City:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    State:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    HighestEducation:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('UserProfile',ProfileSchema);
```

This is my route.js

```
var express = require('express')
var app = module.exports = express.Router();
var UserProfile = require('./models/UserProfile');


app.get('/User', function (req, res) {
    UserProfile.find(function (err, profile) {
        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err) {
           return res.json({"success":false,"msg":err})
           console.log(err);
        }
        res.status(200).send({"success":true,"result":profile}) 
   });
});
```

Here i get the response as GET/User 200 and when I run localhost:8000/User I get this below, the result is empty, I am guessing it can access the Collections but not able to get data.

```
{"success":true,"result":[]}
```

In Mongo DB, I have a database named as testdb
I have a collection named as User
This is a sample of one the entries in the table

```
db.User.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a83d1400d47870303228bfa"),
        "FirstName" : "Jazz",
        "LastName" : "Ben",
        "EmailID" : "abc@gmail.com",
        "Phone" : 7654329878,
        "Address1" : "Golden Tulip Est",
        "Address2" : "Earth",
        "PinCode" : 500084,
        "Gender" : "WhoCares",
        "ProfilePic" : "hugyft.in",
        "IDproof" : "hugyc.in",
        "UserName" : "Jazz",
        "Password" : "1736127",
        "Dob" : 1071985,
        "City" : "TheBest",
        "State" : "Solid",
        "HighestEducation" : "PHD"
}
```

Please help me understand where did I go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Specify the collection name in the userprofile.js

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('UserProfile',ProfileSchema,'User');
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! you saved me a hell lot of time!!